# How install only files from sourceDir with no directories

Tags: wix

I have two source folders "hml" and "prod" with files that has the same name.

- source-files\hml\prop.txt
- source-files\prod\prop.txt

According to an environment variable, the hml or prod folder is installed

WXS File generated from heat.exe

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="DRTest">
            <Directory Id="dir955DBF4D2285F2E21C32C59406B537CE" Name="hml" />
            <Directory Id="dirD719650CC1B2842144EDDEE82C74F4F8" Name="prod" />
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="CGTest">
            <Component Id="cmpEFE4E22AB34DA3EB5B946F5BB2C9607F" Directory="dir955DBF4D2285F2E21C32C59406B537CE" Guid="{34608A80-DED6-4CE1-B270-D74A4EC672D1}">
                <Condition><![CDATA[ENVIRONMENT="H"]]></Condition>
                <File Id="fil6762F479FB1087BFED02566F581D8DC3" KeyPath="yes" Source="SourceDir\hml\prop.txt" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="cmpC8F54E05FD0D1FEB5D23E8E250BDC3CC" Directory="dirD719650CC1B2842144EDDEE82C74F4F8" Guid="{3A60E929-C1CC-4317-9486-05DB5D03EA36}">
                <Condition><![CDATA[ENVIRONMENT="P"]]></Condition>
                <File Id="fil81946DAEA8CB358FB28F167A00902CAC" KeyPath="yes" Source="SourceDir\prod\prop.txt" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="cmp892267248C5EB88377233E323E9CBC61" Directory="dirD719650CC1B2842144EDDEE82C74F4F8" Guid="{3FD22301-A44E-4BB6-AD7C-A91F0AF9E4D7}">
                <Condition><![CDATA[ENVIRONMENT="P"]]></Condition>
                <File Id="fil83C6A493C601DC451F7D48B8005B7489" KeyPath="yes" Source="SourceDir\prod\prop2.txt" />
            </Component>
        </ComponentGroup>
        <Property Id="ENVIRONMENT">
            <RegistrySearch Id="ENVIRONMENT" Root="HKCU" Key="System\CurrentControlSet\Policies" Name="ENVIRONMENT" Type="raw" />
        </Property>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

WXS File with Installer properties

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<Product Id="a09e1fd5-abb0-4a1e-ba61-aa087b8691e7" Name="NameTest" Version="1.0.0" Manufacturer="Manufacturer" UpgradeCode="a09e1fd5-abb0-4a1e-ba61-aa087b8691e6" Language="1033">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" Manufacturer="Manufacturer" />
    <Media Id="1" Cabinet="installer.cab" EmbedCab="yes"/>
    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version is already installed"/>
    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="TitleTeste" Level="1">
        <ComponentGroupRef Id="CGTest"/>
    </Feature>
</Product>
    <Fragment>

        <SetDirectory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Value="C:\test"/>
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" >
                <Directory Id="DRTest"/>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

XSLT

```
<xsl:template match='//wix:Wix/wix:Fragment/wix:ComponentGroup/wix:Component[wix:File[@Source and  (contains(@Source, "hml"))]]'>
  
  <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>    
      <xsl:element name="Condition" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[ENVIRONMENT="H"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:element>    
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>    
  </xsl:copy>
  
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match='//wix:Wix/wix:Fragment/wix:ComponentGroup/wix:Component[wix:File[@Source and  (contains(@Source, "prod"))]]'>
  <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:element name="Condition" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
           <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[ENVIRONMENT="P"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:element>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>    
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

When I run the installer, the target folder looks like this:

c:\test\hml\prop.txt

And I expected

c:\test\prop.txt

I expect just the files from sourceDir be installed

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not match your expectations. You have a `prop.txt` in two different directories: `dir955DBF4D2285F2E21C32C59406B537CE` or `dirD719650CC1B2842144EDDEE82C74F4F8`. Those two directories are:

```
<Directory Id="dir955DBF4D2285F2E21C32C59406B537CE" Name="hml" />
<Directory Id="dirD719650CC1B2842144EDDEE82C74F4F8" Name="prod" />
```

And those two directories are parented into `DRTest` and `INSTALLFOLDER`, which are fallthroughs, but you have a custom action setting `INSTALLFOLDER` to `C:\test`.

So the results you'll get will be:

- `C:\test\hml\prop.txt`
- `C:\test\prod\prod.txt`
- Nothing installed

Based on the value of the registry key (note: you can access environment variables in MSI without searching for them).

Everything is working exactly as you have written.

If you don't want the `hml` or `prod` directories included, then parent the Components to the `INSTALLFOLDER` (or the fallthrough `DRTest`) directory.

Comment: I understand. But I use the directory name(hml and prod) to filter files that will be installed on my xlst. match='//wix:Wix/wix:Fragment/wix:ComponentGroup/wix:Component[wix:File[@Source and  (contains(@Source, "prod"))]] Then, I add condition according environment. I added XLST here. What is the best way to reach the expected result?

Comment: That's an XSLT question. I don't like dealing with XSLT and use [Advanced Harvesting from FireGiant](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/wep-documentation/harvesting/) instead. It is much easier to work with than XSLT (but it is not free).